# how to assign a value to a variable in the template?

Tags: python, django

I have the following code:

```
<img src = "{{MEDIA_URL}} {{get_item_news.image}}" alt = "" style = "float: 
{% If get_item_news.inner_image_position == 'left'%} 
left 
{% Elif get_item_news.inner_image_position == 'right'%} 
right 
{% Endif%} 
"/>
```

help please move if-endif block of attribute and put them before img

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
{% with get_item_news.inner_image_position as alignment %}
  <img src = "{{MEDIA_URL}} {{get_item_news.image}}"
       alt = "" style = "float: {{ alignment }};"/>
{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
{% if get_item_news.inner_image_position == 'left'%}
       <img src = "{{MEDIA_URL}} {{get_item_news.image}}" alt = "" style = "float:left"/> 
{%else%}
       <img src = "{{MEDIA_URL}} {{get_item_news.image}}" alt = "" style = "float:right"/> 
{%endif%}
```